# Python: How to check if a number is in range and if not have the user enter a new number?

Tags: python

I first asked the user to enter a number and then ran a try/except block. I now want to check to see if the number is in a range between 1-9.

If not I want it to check if int and then check if it is in range.

Here is what I have so far:

```
def getInt(low, high):
    start = 0
    while start == 0:
        try:
            num = input("Enter a number for your calculation in range of 1- 9: ")
            num = int(num)
            start = 1
            asdf = 0
            while asdf == 0:
                if num > 9 or num < 0:
                    print("Error: Please only enter numbers between 1-9")
                else:
                    asdf = +1
                    return num
        except:
            print("Error: Please only enter numbers")

# main
TOTAL_NUMBERS = 2
LOW_NUMBER = 1
HIGH_NUMBER = 9

num1 = getInt(LOW_NUMBER, HIGH_NUMBER )
print(num1)
num2 = getInt(LOW_NUMBER, HIGH_NUMBER )
print(num2)
```

Comment: move the 3 lines starting at: `num = input(...` into the while loop. BTW you don't need the external `while start == 0` since you don't use `start` at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you need this:

```
def getInt(low, high):
    while True:
        try:
            num = int(input("Enter a number for your calculation in range of 1- 9: "))
        except ValueError:
            print("Error: Please only enter numbers")
            continue

        if num not in range(1, 10):
            print("Error: Please only enter numbers between 1-9")
        else:
            return num
```

Comment: @AllieHart You should accept the correct answer then other people can  quickly find the answer :)

Answer (score 0):

You could replace

```
print("Error: Please only enter numbers between 1-9")
```

with

```
num = input("Error: Please only enter numbers between 1-9: ")
```

or move

```
num = input("Enter a number for your calculation in range of 1- 9: ")
num = int(num)
```

into the while loop so it gets called again if the user inputs a number outside the range

Answer (score 0):

```
def getInt(low, high):
    while True: # Keep asking until we get a valid number
        try:
            numStr = raw_input("Enter a number for your calculation in range of {0} - {1}: ".format(low, high) )
            if numStr.isdigit():
                num = int(numStr)
                if num <= high and num >= low:
                    return num
        except: # Field left empty
            pass

getInt(1, 9)
```